# I am trying to replace a specific letter within a string

Tags: python, string, replace

For example, my phrase is, phrase = "Good Morning", I am trying to change the second 'o' in 'Good' but I'm stuck.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
phrase = "Good Morning"
print (phrase.replace("o", "i"))
```

Comment: the most strait forward way is simply `phrase.replace("oo","oi")`

Comment: Why are you only trying to replace that o? @Copperfield provided a good way to do so but why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression that matches an `o` after another `o`.

```
import re

phrase = 'Good Morning'
print(re.sub(r'^([^o]*o[^o]*)o', r'\1i', phrase))
```

`[^o]*o[^o]*` matches a string containing 1 `o`. That capture group is copied to `\1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

```
startIndex = 2
phrase = "Good Morning"
print(phrase[0:startIndex] + phrase[startIndex:len(phrase)].replace("o","i") )
```

split it into 2 strings and only do replace() on the second string, then add them back together

Comment: Where did `startIndex` come from?

Comment: This changes `Morning` to `Mirning`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first two o's with i's and then replace the first i with an o.

```
s = "Good morning"
new_s = s.replace("o", "i", 2).replace("i", "o", 1)
print(new_s)
```

Comment: for this sample it does not matter, but this will not work well if there are "i" prior to the "o" in the original string

Answer (score 0):

I think, the o will act on index 1.
Try specifying the index you want to replace.